# Merge 2 list of different types into 1

Tags: c#, list, merge

I have 2 list of different types that i want to group by date and then merge the 2 lists for every date.

My 2 list looks something like this.

```
List<Payment> payments = new List<Payment>
{
    new Payment{Date = '2014-01-01 12:23:52', PaymentSum = 300},
    new Payment{Date = '2014-01-01 12:23:53', PaymentSum = 100},
    new Payment{Date = '2014-01-02 12:23:52', PaymentSum = 300},
}

List<Invoice> invoices = new List<Invoice>
{
    new Invoice{Date = '2014-01-01 12:20:32', InvoiceSum= 300},
    new Invoice{Date = '2014-01-01 12:21:53', InvoiceSum= 200},
    new Invoice{Date = '2014-01-02 12:24:52', InvoiceSum= 300},
}
```

I would like the result to look something like this:

```
List<NewItem> newItems= new List<NewItem>
{
    new NewItem{Date = '2014-01-01', InvoiceSum= 500, PaymentSum = 400},
    new NewItem{Date = '2014-01-02', InvoiceSum= 300, PaymentSum = 300},
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that first selects all distinct dates:

```
var dateSums = payments
    .Select(p => p.Date.Date)
    .Concat(invoices.Select(i => i.Date.Date))
    .Distinct()
    .Select(d => new
    {
        Date = d,
        InvoiceSum = invoices
            .Where(i => i.Date.Date == d)
            .Sum(i => i.InvoiceSum),
        PaymentSum = payments
            .Where(i => i.Date.Date == d)
            .Sum(i => i.PaymentSum)
    });
```

Note that i'm using `Date.Date` since that property is a `DateTime` with time portion.

Answer (score 0):

You could either create a third type

```
class ThirdType {
    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    public Payment Payment { get; set; }
}
```

or use tuples in the resultant lists

```
List<Tuple<Date, Invoice, Payment>>();
```